# Select non NA data from Single Row

Tags: r, dataframe

This should be pretty easy, not sure what I'm missing here.  I want to select a single row from a data frame, let's say row 1000, and get all columns where that specific row is not NA.

This works

```
df<- df[1000,]
df<- df[, !is.na(df)]
```

This fails

```
df<- df[1000, !is.na(df)] 
ERROR "undefined columns selected"
```

Comment: I would bet you're looking for something like this `df <- df[1000, !is.na(df[1000, ])]`

Comment: yup thanks.  that is it.  switching back from python to r now.  seems to require different mindset.

Comment: Will post it as an answer so that you can accept it ;)

Comment: Okay, I was waiting for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed indexing the part concerning with `is.na`, here's an approach:

```
df <- df[1000, !is.na(df[1000, ])]
```